# Can I disable different colored grass?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, server-administration, minecraft-java-edition-server

I made a town which is inbetween 3 biomes, and the grass is colored differently for different sections of the town, making it look very ugly.

Is there a Bukkit plugin I can use to change the color of the grass? Other methods besides Bukkit plugins are fine, but a plugin would be preferred.

Comment: There would probably be a way to edit the chunks to mark them as being all in the same biome, but just leave their contents looking like the biome they are originally from. So, please state what the 3 biomes are so we know the pros and cons of this possibility.

Comment: Just for clarification, are you asking about the grass blocks, or the grass that is growing on the blocks?

Comment: @Coronus Both. :P

Comment: @musicwithoutpaper The structures (trees, dungeons, etc) I don't mind, (in fact, they are helpful) but the difference in the color/texture of the grass is annoying.

Comment: Must it be a bukkit plugin, or are other ways of altering the colour acceptable?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Bukkit Plugins are preferred, but other ways are acceptable, as long as I don't have to download anything or utilize a glitch/bug. I'm fine with downloading MCedit, if that can work?

Comment: Might! (I'm not familiar enough with it.) The more specific you make the acceptable methods for the solution, the less likely you'll get a working solution. I'd suggest editing to say just what you said: plugins preferred, other tools are ok.

Comment: Why not just a client side texture pack that hides the grass discolouration?

Comment: @Robotnik I am using this for a server, and want all my users to be able to not have to see the ugly change in color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that the best approach is to use an editor to change the biome of all the chunks in the area to be the same, without changing the blocks on the chunks.

This will make the grass in the village to be consistent.

There could be side-effects, for example certain mobs only spawn in certain biomes.

I expect that this could be accomplished with MCEdit. You would need to stop the server, then open the world with MCEdit, change the chunks to be a different biome, then save, then start the server back.

Alternatively, it may be possible to use WorldEdit which is a Bukkit plugin. I don't actually know if it allows changing of the biome, you'd have to look into it. Either way, I suggest you consider installing WorldEdit anyway. It is very handy to be able to copy/paste whole buildings, or generate a huge wall with a few commands.

Comment: What would I have to do once in MCEdit in order to change a selected area's biome?

Comment: [I don't know. Google does.](https://www.google.com/search?q=MCEdit+change+biome)

Answer (score 5):

You stated bukkit plugins were preferred, but other ways are acceptable. You cannot change the grass look for the whole server, as it is generally a client side feature. In other words, how one person sees grass is completely different to how another one sees it as they may have texture packs and other client side mods which alter the look of things.

- You can install a server texture pack which minimises these effects
  for the whole server.
- You could find a plugin to change the biomes of your surrounding town. This would change all the biomes to match and not change grass
  color.

Comment: This only changes the sides of grass blocks. It still leaves the top of the block's color biome-specific.

Comment: No it doesn't, it actually defaults all of them to what is in the texture pack as well. At least for me, this is the case, also there are alternatives to using optifine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but this is what I get, and I don't have any texture modifcations or anything: http://i1113.photobucket.com/albums/k501/JonnyBGood44/cd006b5e14ee917174f41bc19a8bc0c1.jpg

Comment: If you head over to the forest, does the grass on top change color with grass set to fast?

Comment: No, and it shouldn't since it only edits grasses side textures, for performance purposes.

Comment: That is what my answer is supposed to do. Without this on, grass from different biomes have different colors and shades on top.

Comment: That setting doesn't change grass top textures. It only changed the side texture to either default green (fast) or biome colour (fancy). Top textures are left alone entirely.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. I have been using an old computer recently and the grass (for whatever reason) doesn't change color on the top, so I assumed that what I had done worked. I just played on my newer computer and the tops change color. I transferred worlds and the tops still had different colors where they were the same on my older computer. :I Feel like an idiot...

Answer (score 2):

[WorldEdit](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/worldedit/) is able to change the biome of parts of the world using the command `/setbiome`.

When it comes to biomes, WorldEdit considers the map two-dimensional - height (y) is irrelevant. It looks at the world in "columns".

The `/setbiome` command changes all columns within a WorldEdit selection to the biome specified as an argument to the `/setbiome` command. For example: `/setbiome jungle` would set all columns in your WorldEdit selection to the jungle biome.

In detail, you would go about it in the following way (for simplicity's sake, we'll use a rectangular selection. Fore other selection methods, please refer to the [wiki](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Selection)):

1. Take your wand, which is by default a wooden axe, and **left** click one corner of the (in this example rectangular) area you would like to change the biome of. After that, go to the other corner of the rectangle and click it with your **right** mouse button. Mind that the depth of your selection (how many blocks it encompasses on the y-coordinate) is irrelevant when it comes to the /setbiome command.
2. Use the command `/setbiome BIOMENAME`, where BIOMENAME is what biome you want. For example, `/setbiome jungle` or `/setbiome desert`.
3. This step is not required, but I recommend using `//desel` once you don't need a selection anymore. It cancels your selection and decreases the risk of accidentally inflicting damage on your project.

**Note:** Changes to the biome will not be recognized by the Minecraft client immediately. I recommend you re-log in after you changed the biome of an area to reload the new biome settings

Answer (score 1):

Tired of dreary blu-ish Grass?

[image]

Then download this! https://www.dropbox.com/s/xe7v4p639o60zzm/Vanilla%20with%20Green%20Grass.zip
[image]
You'll have lush green grass and foliage all across your minecraft world! Just put this in your resourcepack folder

### DIY Custom Colored Grass and Foliage

You'll need a zip program (WinRAR or 7-zip are two good ones) and a paint program (default paint will work).
Download the file above and open it. Go into assets->minecraft->colormap. There are two files there, foliage and grass, edit them to your liking in your paint program. Dependent on what color you place where, it will only affect a certain biome.

Here are the two original pictures:

[image] [image]

The downside to this is that you will have to get everyone to download this on the server, and the grass color will be world-wide. Enjoy!

Comment: Doesn't this do primarily the same thing as a texture pack?

Comment: Servers can automatically offer to install texture packs when a client connects, so that's actually not a problem.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yeah, but it's not a required though, just optional, so some people might not download it...

Comment: @Jonny their loss?